# fann_set_bit_fail_limit() fails to actually set the bit fail limit, forcing me to manually edit the ANN file

Tags: c++, fann

```
struct fann *ann;
ann = fann_create_standard(3, 600, 1200, 30);
fann_set_activation_function_hidden(ann, FANN_SIGMOID);
fann_set_activation_function_output(ann, FANN_SIGMOID);
fann_set_bit_fail_limit(ann, 0.002);
fann_save(ann, "ann.net");
```

Whenever I load this neural network from the file and read `fann_get_bit_fail_limit()`, the returned value is the default 0.35 instead of the 0.002 I tried to set. I have to edit the ANN file manually for it to take effect.

I am using `doublefann.h`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "*Am I doing something wrong?*"

As per [Documentation - FANN Training > Parameters > `fann_get_bit_fail_limit`](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_get_bit_fail_limit) (emphasis added) :

> The bit fail limit is used during training **where** the [fann_stopfunc_enum](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_data-h.html#fann_stopfunc_enum) is set to `FANN_STOPFUNC_BIT`.

Example :

```
fann_set_train_stop_function(ann, FANN_STOPFUNC_BIT);
fann_set_bit_fail_limit(ann, 0.002);
fann_save(ann, "ann.net");
```

Just in case:

> I am using `doublefann.h`.

Link `-ldoublefann` instead of `-lfann`.

Comment: I figured as such by myself by messing around with it. I did use the bit stop function, but it didn't occur to me to use it as a training function, because unlike the other training functions, this one does not begin with `fann_set_train_`.

Comment: @daedsidog [Training algorithm](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_set_training_algorithm), [-stop function](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_set_train_stop_function) and [-error function](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_train-h.html#fann_set_train_error_function) are distinct parameters to the process; `fann_set_train_error_function` has [`FANN_ERRORFUNC_TANH`](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files/fann_data-h.html#fann_errorfunc_enum) "*... not recommended for cascade training and incremental training.*".